# Error creating Kibana 6 pid file in /var/run/ directory

Tags: centos7, kibana

I have installed Kibana 6 in Centos 7.4 and I have configured pid file location to /var/run/mypidfile.pid. **I want to write in this location because when server is rebooted, I need that Kibana starts automatically.**

I have tried changing pid file location to under kibana owned directory. It only works when I start and stop manually the process, but not when the server is rebooted. Whether /var/run/mypidfile.pid location is setted previusly with right Kibana permissions, It is not valid after server has been rebooted.

Journalctl shows this.

> may 02 03:42:22 SERVER.localdomain kibana[4509]: at Error (native)
>
> may 02 03:42:22 SERVER.localdomain kibana[4509]: { Error:  EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/run/mypidfile.pid'
>
> may 02 03:42:22 SERVER.localdomain kibana[4509]: cause:
>
> may 02 03:42:22 SERVER.localdomain kibana[4509]: at Error (native)
>
> may 02 03:42:22 SERVER.localdomain kibana[4509]: FATAL { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/run/mypidfile.pid'
>
> may 02 03:42:22 SERVER.localdomain kibana[4509]: {"type":"error","@timestamp":"2018-05-02T08:42:22Z","tags":["fatal"],"
> may 02 03:42:20 SERVER.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Kibana...

SELinux:

> Enforcing

I have reviewed audit.log file. There were no messages.

/etc/kibana.yml

> pid.file: /var/run/mypidfile.pid

I have tried to resolve it by setting some unit-d file variables.

> ExecStartPre=touch /var/run/mypidfile.pid
>
> ExecStartPre=chown kibana /var/run/mypidfile.pid

It did not work. So, I tried with another variable, dropping after-mentioned variables.

> PIDFile=/var/run/mypidfile.pid

Are there another manner to do this?

Answer (score 0):

according to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.0/rpm.html#rpm-configuring
the default configuration file should be `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml` not /etc/kibana.yml.